# how to compile an external library and add it to my Android Studio project

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android dev and I'm hoping these questions have easy answers:

I'm trying to add [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation) to my Android Studio project.  I've managed to get it to work with an on-internet dev box, but now I'm trying to do the same  to an offline one.

I think I want to add it as a "library", not as a "module" because I don't want to change it and deal with future version merging.

I've downloaded the release tar.gz file and the only .jar or .aar file I see is "gradle-wrapper.jar".  Why'd they include compiled  gradle code?

Should I extract this .tar.gz and point Android Studio to it to treat it as a separate project in order to compile a .aar/.jar file?  What do I look for to know which directory to treat the the project-directory?  Multiple directories include build.gradle files.

Once I have a .jar/.aar, where should I put it exactly? There are so many "lib" directories in here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The project you wanted to add is available in an online maven repository. You could add it with Gradle with a few lines of script instead of downloading and compiling from source, then adding manually to the library directory.

Gradle is a dependency manager which is able to pull dependencies from online repositories and add it to the project automatically. Depending on your IDE, you may need to install plugins related to Gradle/Maven before proceeding. Then, follow the instructions given in the project's Readme under "Installation". Just by adding those lines in `build.gradle`, Your IDE should begin to download the library from the repository and add it to your project.

Comment: I've actually done that and it worked.  Now I'm trying to do it in a more secure, offline dev box.  :-)

Comment: My bad, missed out that point in your question. Once you get the .jar, you could include the dependency by going to File -> Project structure. Then on the library tab on the left, you could click on '+' to add a new java library.

Comment: I wish I understood what's happening better.  I see my online dev box has made an .aar file in a gradle cache: .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation/v1.0.1/aac90c9533ed4f403c86a2e2721147dda4e7c571/Android-SimpleLocation-v1.0.1.aar

Comment: If I move that to what I hope is the best libs dir (~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/libs), and go offline, compiling the project errors with b/c it can't find or re-create the file:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download Android-SimpleLocation.aar (com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1)

Comment: I'm looking at my dependencies (Android Studio: File: Project Structure: my app module: Dependencies).  Should I add this .aar file as a Library or Module?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!
Wow, this is not intuitive.  This whole system seems to really, really want an internet connection.  How do more serious companies develop software for Android?  Surely they're not grabbing just whatever files are hanging around external repositories and going with it are they?

Answer's from here:  http://www.b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/using-local-android-library-packages-aar/

There seems to be no way to do this in the GUI.

Gradle and Android Studio don't support .AAR files as well as they do .JAR files.  Which strikes me as strange. I guess there are more differences between those file formats than I thought.

To bring in an external .AAR file:

1. copy it somewhere your dev box can access.  The most logical place seems to be "AndroidStudioProjects/*yourapp*/app/libs"
2. tell gradle about it by adding the "repository" and "compile" lines below to your app module's gradle file (AndroidStudioProjects//app/build.gradle):

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> // first important part: tell gradle to treat the libs folder as a repo.
> repositories{
>     flatDir {
>         dirs 'libs'
>     }
> }
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 26
>     buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.example.user.simplelocationtester"
>         minSdkVersion 14
>         targetSdkVersion 26
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
> ```
>
> {
>               exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
>           })
>           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
>           compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
>           testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>
> ```
>     //here's the 2nd important part: specify the AAR file
>     compile(name:'Android-SimpleLocation-v1.0.1', ext:'aar')
> }
> ```